# zend core files used to connect to database

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using a working zend application that connects to a sybase database. i'm new to this framework. can some tell me which core files are used in zend to make the connection to the database?

say these are the database parameters in application.ini file

```
resources.db.params.host = "servername"
resources.db.params.username = "username"
resources.db.params.password = "password"
resources.db.params.dbname = "db1"
```

i need to see all the non-zend functions that are used in core, so i can make a connection to sybase in php (the same way zend does). 
hope i'm clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

In the Zend project tree, look for

```
  Library/Zend/Db/Adapter
```

This folder has the adapters for different database types.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i'check that.

Answer (score 1):

It is just using PHP's [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) database functions with the [DBLIB](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php) adapter.

```
$dsn = "sybase:host=servername;dbname=db1";
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, 'username', 'password');

$res = $pdo->query('select * from whatever');
while ( $res as $row ) {
    // ...
 }
```

See the [PDO class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your reply, actually i found out that this zend app is using php sybase functions in the Base.php file.

Answer (score 0):

i've found some useful information into the Base.php file. 
so this zend application is using php sybase functions to connect to the database instead of pdo

```
        if($this->pdoConnection)
            AppliName_Model_Base::$globConn = new PDO('dblib:host='.self::$dbConfig['host'].';dbname='
                .self::$dbConfig['name'].';charset='
                .self::$dbConfig['charset'],self::$dbConfig['user'] ,self::$dbConfig['password']);
        else{
            sybase_min_server_severity(11);
            sybase_connect(self::$dbConfig['host'],self::$dbConfig['user'],self::$dbConfig['password'],self::$dbConfig['charset']);
            AppliName_Model_Base::$globConn  = sybase_select_db(self::$dbConfig['name']);
        }
```

i did the same connection in a php file:

```
$link = sybase_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASSWORD, DBCHARSET) or die("no connection!");
```

It's working.